# Anchor link scrolls into overflow content of overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

I recently discovered that in-page anchors scroll beyond the edges of an element with `overflow: hidden`.

See here - scroll to bottom, see the item that is cut off by the overflow. Scroll back to top and click the anchor. It jumps down beyond bottom of overlow. Then try to scroll all the way back to the top of the page; you cannot as the anchor/top part of the page is cut off.

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

.page {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 200vh; /* just to create scroll */
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
}

.target {
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div id="top"><a href="#anchor">Jump to target</a></div>
  <div class="content">        
    <div class="target" id="anchor"><a href="#top">Target</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Two questions:

1) Why does it do this? Is this a bug/quirk, or intended behaviour? E.g. the overflow is hidden but still scrollable.

2) Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: you haven't given your page a height? assign a height and then retry. Also you have padding on your content of 200vh? is that supposed to be 200px or is why have you set it to twice the total vertical height?

Comment: Ah, my bad - I was using 200vh just to create page scroll, it's an arbitrary number. I'll make that clearer in the example. I can't give the page an overall fixed height though as it should be flexible based on content length.

Comment: @iankeir, you don't need to 'create' a scroll; if items overflow, then the page will scroll naturally. Remove the padding of 200vh

Comment: I'm creating scroll for the purposes of demonstrating the problem in the demo code. The problem I have defined is fundamentally tied to scrolling. I could have just put a bunch of lorem ipsum paragraphs in for the same purpose but chose padding. It isn't relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

just change at target class `top: 95%;` to `bottom: 0;`

After change:

in css

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

.page {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 200vh;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
}

.target {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div id="top"><a href="#anchor">Jump to target</a></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="target" id="anchor"><a href="#top">Target</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the absolutely positioned item needs to overflow.